# WSJT-X integration with Ham Radio Deluxe not working for automatic logging

Tags: wsjt-x, ham-radio-deluxe

I have both Ham Radio Deluxe and WSJT-X configured the way the documentation recommends:

[image]

but when a QSO finishes in WSJT-X it's just not logged to HRD. Nothing happens, there's no errors. Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the answer was that my Ham Radio Deluxe was outdated. I found on that computer I was running an old version (not by much, maybe a month or two). Upgrading to v6.8.0.372 (13-Feb. 2023) fixed the issue.